How to scroll the horizontal calendar to the current week (.Net Maui)?
I am trying to create a horizontal calendar in .Net Maui. It's working well, but there are two issues that I can't solve. I am attaching the code for your reference:
<!--Horizonal calendar-->
<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" x:Name="CalendarScrollView">
    <StackLayout x:Name="CalendarStackLayout" Orientation="Horizontal">

    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>

logic:
public partial class CalendarPage : ContentPage
{
    public CalendarPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddFramesToStackLayout();
        ScrollToCurrentWeekStart();
    }

    private void AddFramesToStackLayout()
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime startOfCurrentWeek = today.AddDays(-(int)today.DayOfWeek);

        AddWeekFramesToStackLayout(startOfCurrentWeek.AddDays(-7));
        AddWeekFramesToStackLayout(startOfCurrentWeek);
        AddWeekFramesToStackLayout(startOfCurrentWeek.AddDays(7));
    }


    private void AddWeekFramesToStackLayout(DateTime startOfWeek)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            DateTime currentDate = startOfWeek.AddDays(i);
            bool isCurrentDay = (currentDate.Date == DateTime.Today.Date);

            var frame = new Frame
            {
                BackgroundColor = isCurrentDay ? Color.FromHex("#8380FF") : Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF"),
                CornerRadius = 10,
                BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#6B779A"),
                Padding = new Thickness(5),
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 3, 0),
                WidthRequest = 48,
                HeightRequest = 70
            };

            var labelNumber = new Label
            {
                Text = currentDate.Day.ToString(),
                FontSize = 14,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };

            var labelDay = new Label
            {
                Text = GetDayOfWeek(currentDate.DayOfWeek),
                FontSize = 12,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };

            var stackLayout = new StackLayout
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };

            stackLayout.Children.Add(labelNumber);
            stackLayout.Children.Add(labelDay);
            frame.Content = stackLayout;

            frame.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
            {
                Command = new Command(() =>
                {
                    foreach (var child in CalendarStackLayout.Children)
                    {
                        if (child is Frame frameChild)
                        {
                            frameChild.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF");
                            frameChild.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#6B779A");

                            if (frameChild.Content is StackLayout stackLayoutChild)
                            {
                                foreach (var element in stackLayoutChild.Children)
                                {
                                    if (element is Label label)
                                    {
                                        label.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#6B779A");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    frame.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#8380FF");
                    frame.BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#6B779A");
                    labelNumber.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF");
                    labelDay.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF");
                })
            });

            CalendarStackLayout.Children.Add(frame);
        }
    }

    private void ScrollToCurrentWeekStart()
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime startOfWeek = today.AddDays(-(int)today.DayOfWeek);

        var sundayFrame = CalendarStackLayout.Children
            .OfType<Frame>()
            .FirstOrDefault(frame => (frame.Content as StackLayout)?.Children
                .OfType<Label>()
                .Any(label => label.Text == startOfWeek.AddDays(6).Day.ToString()) ?? false);

        if (sundayFrame != null)
        {
            CalendarScrollView.ScrollToAsync(sundayFrame, ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, true);
        }
    }



    private string GetDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek day)
    {
        return day.ToString().Substring(0, 3).ToUpper();
    }
}

Here I have a three week calendar: previous, current and next.
I have created a ScrollToCurrentWeekStart method where I try to scroll to the current week when the application starts. But it doesn't work
So the two main questions are:

How to scroll down to the current week? (This is the main question).
Can anyone tell me how to set an unlimited number of previous and future weeks, so that they dynamically load when scrolling?


Do you use ScrollToCurrentWeekStart() to scroll to the current week?

It's not working for some reason

I think you can try to convert AddFramesToStackLayout into XAML code as this will be easier to view the structure of the Calendar frame.
